# How to colspan in kivy with python

Tags: python, kivy

How can I make this layout in kivy without .kv file?

[image: colspan layout]

Basically all i want to do is to fit Button2 and button3 in tha same column

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class TestApp(App):
def build(self):
    root = FloatLayout()
    layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    button1 = TextInput(size_hint=(1,.7))
    button2 = TextInput(size_hint=(1,.2))
    button3 = Button(text='Send',size_hint=(1, .1))
    layout.add_widget(button1)
    layout.add_widget(button2)
    layout.add_widget(button3)
    root.add_widget(layout)
    return root

 TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Can you show your code, what you have tried so far? (See [mcve])

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use kv file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Button2 and Button3 to a different BoxLayout and then add this BoxLayout as a child of `layout`.
So something like this inside your `build` method:

```
root = FloatLayout()
layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
layout1 = BoxLayout()
button1 = TextInput()
button2 = TextInput()
button3 = Button()
layout.add_widget(button1)
layout1.add_widget(button2)
layout1.add_widget(button3)
layout.add_widget(layout1)
root.add_widget(layout)
```

I'm assuming this is the behaviour you expect to get:

[image]

Comment: That's Exactly What I Wanted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

To build what is in the image you've got 4 buttons and two box layouts, one nested inside the other. You shouldn't need size hints because the heights of the 2 rows are the same and the width of the bottom 3 buttons are the same. There is no need for a float layout in the above image.

```
class TestApp(App):
def build(self):
    # layout for the outer box layout to handle the rows
    layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    # layout for the inner box layout, which is the bottom 3 columns
    bottom_row = BoxLayout(size_hint_y=0.6)  # Defaults to horizontal orientation

    # Make the buttons
    button1 = TextInput()    
    button2 = TextInput()
    button3 = Button()
    button4 = Button()

    # Add the first button and then bottom row to the layout. Add the bottom 3 buttons to the bottom_row box layout.
    layout.add_widget(button1)
    bottom_row.add_widget(button2)
    bottom_row.add_widget(button3)
    bottom_row.add_widget(button4)
    layout.add_widget(bottom_row)

return layout
```

Comment: How can i make the first layout to be bigger? Now both of the layouts cover equal 50% of the space,can i make the first to cover more space?

Comment: Yes, they both rows will have the same height. You can use the various size_hint attributes for the safest way to adjust the proportions. The numbers are only compared to each other, so if foo has a size_hint of 1 and bar has a size_hint of 2, the screen will be split into thirds with bar being twice as big as foo. But this would be the same if foo's size_hint was 5 and bar's was 10. I'll add it into the above code.

Comment: running your code gives me this
http://s18.postimg.org/w5a7uhpdl/Capture.png
All the objects are arrenge horizontal,this isn't what i want

Comment: I was being daft, and setting the sizes of the rows comparatively, whereas it's actually one inside the other. So layout needs no size hint, it will default to 1 and fill the whole screen. That way you can use size_hint with bottom row, comparing it to 1 to determine the height of the row. I've updated the code above to demonstrate.

Comment: Thank you my friend this works fine! I have a hard time switching from Tkinter to kivy :P

Answer (score 0):

Try with this, the concept is similar to Paul, I create first a general block, and add small components, in this case the main  is Box Layout. I add a input text and later the buttons

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput



class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        # layout for the inner box layout, which is the bottom 3 columns
        bottom_row = GridLayout(size_hint_y=1, cols=5)  # Defaults to horizontal orientation

        # Make the buttons
        button1 = TextInput()    

        # Add the first button and then bottom row to the layout. Add the bottom 3 buttons to the bottom_row box layout.
        layout.add_widget(button1)
        for i in range(10):
            bottom_row.add_widget(Button(text=str(i)))

        layout.add_widget(bottom_row)

        return layout

TestApp().run()
```